# Prediction Dataframe with Multiple Factors

Tags: r

I am try to create a prediction data frame for a model that I ran that has 2 factor and a continuous variable. The data frame I want to create to plot model predictions for the first factor is given below:

```
Preds.Month = data.frame(Month = factor(1:12), 
                         VegeType = factor(1:12), 
                         DistAgriLand = median(a$DistAgriLand, na.rm = TRUE))
```

But I get this message:
Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) :
factor VegeType has new levels 6

However, if I remove the factor VegeType from the model, re-fit the model and try to create the prediction data frame it works fine. I am not sure what the error is and how to resolve it, any help would be greatly appreciated. I do know that despite VegeType having 12 levels, only 5 have data in them if this plays apart in the error.

Here is some sample data:

```
a = structure(list(Month = structure(c(9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 10L, 12L, 12L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 10L, 10L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 10L, 10L, 3L, 
6L, 6L, 10L, 10L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 10L, 10L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 
10L, 10L, 12L, 12L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 8L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"), class = "factor"), 
    VegeType = structure(c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "7", "8", "9", "10", 
    "11", "12"), class = "factor"), DistAgriLand = c(580.5, 580.5, 
    580.5, 580.5, 580.5, 580.5, 580.5, 580.5, 580.5, 580.5, 580.5, 
    580.5, 580.5, 580.5, 580.5, 580.5, 580.5, 580.5, 580.5, 580.5, 
    580.5, 580.5, 580.5, 580.5, 580.5, 580.5, 580.5, 580.5, 580.5, 
    580.5, 580.5, 580.5, 580.5, 580.5, 580.5, 580.5, 580.5, 580.5, 
    580.5, 580.5, 580.5, 580.5, 580.5, 580.5, 580.5, 580.5, 580.5, 
    580.5, 580.5, 580.5, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 
    594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 
    594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 
    594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 
    594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 
    594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 
    594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37)), row.names = c(NA, 
100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: a$VegeType is 100 elements long.., but the other elements (Month and DistAgrLand) are 12 and 1, respectively. The latter will be recycled (and constant), but the first will not be.

Comment: Therefore, you need to specify what month values you want to have for those 100 rows in  Preds.Month

Comment: also VegeType has only 11 levels (1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,and 12).. It is missing 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the missing level to VegeType:

```
Preds.Month = data.frame(Month = factor(1:12), 
                         VegeType = c(levels(a$VegeType),6), 
                         DistAgriLand = median(a$DistAgriLand, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Output:

```
   Month VegeType DistAgriLand
1      1        1      587.435
2      2        2      587.435
3      3        3      587.435
4      4        4      587.435
5      5        5      587.435
6      6        7      587.435
7      7        8      587.435
8      8        9      587.435
9      9       10      587.435
10    10       11      587.435
11    11       12      587.435
12    12        6      587.435
```

However, the better approach is to make sure that when you create vegeType in the first place, you have level 6 in there.  i.e. `levels=(1:12)`, whereas currently in your provided structure, you have all values are "6", but the `.Label = c(1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12)`. Did you intend to label VegeType=6 with "7"?

Finally, if you want to predict for all levels of month and vegetype, you can do this

```
Preds.Month = setNames(
  cbind(
    expand.grid(1:12, 1:12),
    median(a$DistAgriLand,na.rm=T)
  ), c("Month", "VegeType", "DistAgriLand")
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, this worked to create the data frame but when I used the predict function I got the error Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) : 
factor VegeType has new levels 6.

Comment: Should I post this as a separate question?

Comment: I think you just need to decide what combinations of month and vegetype you want to predict?  The above, shows one set of 12, but perhaps you want all combinations of month and vegetype? (12x12).

Comment: Regarding the error you got, that is simply because you added a level in the predict dataframe, without adding that level in the original data. If you add that level to vegetype  and then run the estimation model, then you'll be able to produce the pred frame as above without having to add level 6

Comment: see my edit above

Comment: Yes I do want to predict for all combinations of VegeType and Month, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Its okay, I have now answered my own question with the solution being to use expand.grid(). Sorry for wasting your time

Comment: no problem, you can post your own answer to the question, and accept you own solution, if you like.